# Class directive dynamically adding another directives

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I'm trying to create an angular directive (as a class) which dynamically adds a angular ui tooltip to the same element. I've tried following, which unfortunately does not work.

```
  MyApp.directive('ellipsis', [
    '$compile', '$parse', '$timeout',
    function ($compile, $parse, $timeout) {
      // Runs during compile
      return {
        restrict: 'C',
        // terminal: true,
        // priority: 1000,
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
          var refresh = false;
          if (attrs.uibTooltip == null) {
            // attrs.$set('uibTooltip', "{{ tooltipText }}");
            element.attr('uib-tooltip', "{{ tooltipText }}");
            refresh = true;
          }
          if (attrs.uibTooltipEnable == null) {
            // attrs.$set('uibTooltipEnable', "{{ ellipsisVisible }}");
            element.attr('uib-tooltip-enable', "{{ ellipsisVisible }}");
            refresh = true;
          }

          if (refresh) {
            $compile(element);
          }

          return function(scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            if (!refresh) {
              return;
            }

            scope.$watch(function () {
              return iElm[0].scrollWidth > iElm[0].offsetWidth;
            }, function(ellipsisVisible) {
              console.log("[mg] watch1", ellipsisVisible);
              scope.ellipsisVisible = ellipsisVisible;
            });

            scope.$watch(function () {
              return iAttrs.title == null ? iElm.text() : $parse(iAttrs.title);
            }, function(tooltipText) {
              console.log("[mg] watch2", tooltipText);
              scope.tooltipText = tooltipText;
            });
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

The reason for adding `refresh` variable is to prevent infinite recursion (so that we compile only when any attribute is added to the element).

PS: The value in the scope is fine (as expected) and there are attributes added to the element also (eg. the generated markup looks like `<a class="ellipsis" uib-tooltip="{{ tooltipText }}" uib-tooltip-enable="{{ ellipsisVisible }}" >Some long overflowing text</a>`), but it does not bind to the scope values.

I'm suspecting the `attrs.$set` is setting the expression value literally, instead of an expression.

Any help in terms of examples or documentation links is welcome. Thanks.

PS: I've created a small example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mihirgokani007/8LMwz/165/).